# Couldn't match type Char with [Char], Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have recently started learning Haskell and I have encountered a problem with dictionaries. I use a key to get the integer number from the dictionary, and GHCi prints an error "Couldn't match type Char with [Char]" on the line where I use a first element of the string as key for a dictionary. Here is the code:

```
import Data.Map
mapRomantoInt :: Map String Int
mapRomantoInt = fromList[("I",1),("V",5),("IX",9),("X",10),("L",50),("C",100),("D",500),("M",1000)]

romanToInt :: String -> Int
romanToInt _ = 0
romanToInt c = if length c == 1 then mapRomantoInt ! head c else
                      let first = mapRomantoInt ! head c
                          second = mapRomantoInt ! (c !! 1)
                          others = romanToInt(tail c)
                      in if first < second then others - first else others + first
```

Comment: `head c` is a character. Use `[head c]` instead. Same with `c !! 1`: should be `[c !! 1]`.

Comment: Note that this programing style is both inefficient (`length` scans the whole list), dangerous (functions like `head, tail, !!` will crash the program when the list is too short), and incorrect (`romanToInt`, as written, always returns `0`). I would strongly recommend you avoid this non idiomatic style and try to exploit pattern matching instead, which is safer and more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Haskell, `String` is a synonym for `[Char]`.

The `c` in `romanToInt` has the type `String`, i.e. `[Char]`.

The type of `head` is `[a] -> a`, so `head c` has the type `Char`.

The type of `(!)` is `Ord k => Map k a -> k -> a`. In this case, `mapRomantoInt` has the type `Map String Int`, so the `k` in question must be `String`.

The function call `mapRomantoInt ! head c`, however, tries to pass a `Char` instead of a `[Char]` (`String`).

There are other problems with the code in the OP, but try to fix the compilation error(s) first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've changed head c to [head c] and it worked perfectly!